# Why does coerce 2.coerce(3.3) return [3.3, 2.0]?

Tags: ruby

If I enter

```
1.1.coerce(1)
```

`Fixnum` is coerced to `Float`:

```
[1.0,1.1]
```

but when I try:

```
1.coerce(1.1)
```

I got:

```
[1.1,1.0]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read on: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce

> ### coerce(numeric) → array
>
> If a numeric is the same type as num, returns an array containing numeric and num. **Otherwise, returns an array with both a numeric and num represented as Float objects.**
>
> This coercion mechanism is used by Ruby to handle mixed-type numeric operations: it is **intended to find a compatible common type** between the two operands of the operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hierarchy between subclasses of numbers in the sense that an instance of one class can be converted to another class without losing information but not vice versa. The [hierarchy](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/glossary.html) goes (actually, the order between `Rational` and `Float` seems the opposite to me, and I don't know why it is like this):

```
Fixnum -> Bignum -> Rational -> Float -> Complex
```

When you have a `Fixnum` and `Float`, you can convert the `Fixnum` instance into a `Float` without losing information, so that is what is done. If `Float` were to be converted to a `Fixnum`, that would mean loss of information.